# Python change logfile location at runtime

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging.config file that specifies handlers outputting logs to the console and to a file. How would I go about changing the file location of the file handler at runtime but keeping all of the formatting, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I found out how to do it. Under `[handler_file]` add this line for the output file:

```
args=('%(logfilename)s',)
```

Then when initializing logger specify the log file location like so:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.config',
                          defaults={'logfilename': '/path/to/log/file'})
```